# Xcode: 'RegisterMonoModules.h' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a Unity game in an existing iOS app with this Tutorial (https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity) from Github.

After struggeling with a lot of other errors now I come to the error:

> *'RegisterMonoModules.h' file not found*

And of course, in my Unity game folder, there is no RegisterMonoModules.h file. There is only RegisterMonoModules.cpp file. 
And if I change the filetyp from ".h" to ".cpp" the file will be found, but it doesn't include the function "RegisterMonoModules()".

I searched and found that this error depends on the fact, that I used il2cpp as scripting background in Unity.

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegisterMonoModules.h` is located in the `Libraries` subfolder of the Xcode-Project *(the one that copies all the files from the unity-exported-xcode-project)* after copying from the unity-exported-xcode-project.

You need to add `Libraries/RegisterMonoModules.cpp` to your Target.
You can check this in the Xcode inspector, after selecting the file, look if there is a checkmark at `Target Membership`.

Following files from the `Libraries` folder must have the `Target Membership` set:

- `Libraries/Il2CppOptions.cpp`
- `Libraries/RegisterFeatures.cpp`
- `Libraries/RegisterMonoModules.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i cant add the files to the target. If i look at the single file there is no checkmark at target membership. And if i want to click at the checkbox nothing happens. I also tried to add the single file with set checkmark at the beginning but if i click at the single file there is no checkmark and i cant set this.

Comment: That's odd. Do you use the *swift-unity*-ios-project? Are you able to build the *unity-exported-xcode-project*? Check their `.cpp`-files `Target Membership`.

Comment: I found no Libraries/RegisterMonoModules.cpp file in Unity 2022.1.12.
I guess it might be removed from the latest version.

Do you have any suggestion on this ?

Comment: @microstrip the question is based on an old unity version (2017) that was not able to build as a library. the current unity version (2022) works different in most aspects. I recommend you to look into UaaL: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example 
If you want a swift integration: I had success with this approach: https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-ios-app.685219/page-3#post-5298738.

Answer (score 0):

'RegisterMonoModules.h' file used in facebook sdk for unity3d.
But this header file has not using anymore. 
So you can solve this problem by deleting this line in FBUnityInterface.mm file at your unity project.

Please check this link.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/323

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Native Xcode project

Find the Libraries Folder which dragged from Unity.

Create a new file named exactly 'RegisterMonoModules.h' under the Libraries Folder.

paste below code inside that file,

```
//#ifndef RegisterMonoModules_h
#define RegisterMonoModules_h
#if !INIT_SCRIPTING_BACKEND

extern void RegisterAllClassesGranular();
void RegisterAllClasses()
{
    // Register classes for unit tests
    RegisterAllClassesGranular();
}

void RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls() {}

void InvokeRegisterStaticallyLinkedModuleClasses() {}
extern "C" void RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() {}

#endif /* RegisterMonoModules_h */

void RegisterMonoModules() {}
```